# Is it possible to 'grab' an elements style with React and render it onto the DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

For example, say I have a dynamically rendered background.

If you Inspect Element, the code would show this, dummy code for eg.

```
<div id="sectionHere" style="background: linear-gradient(117deg, rgb(149, 77, 143), rgb(180, 95, 95))">
```

But in my code editor, with React, it would be like:

```
<div id="sectionHere" style="{gradientFunction}">
```

gradientFunction would be:

```
const gradientFunction  = {
background: linear-gradient(117deg, rgb(149, 77, 143), rgb(180, 95, 95))
}
```

Again, dummy text, but I hope you get the idea.

Say I wanted to render the raw html code onto a page to showcase the code and the results, this specific code line in the first code snippet

```
background: linear-gradient(117deg, rgb(149, 77, 143), rgb(180, 95, 95))
```

Is there any way its possible to grab that from the dom, and render it into a react element? rather than typing it out manually in react? something like in these steps.

1. React renders the code out with the gradientFunction function
2. Another function grabs the output of that function which is "linear-gradient(117deg, rgb(149, 77, 143), rgb(180, 95, 95))"
3. That output is rendered onto the page.

One e.g is from my personal project, a gradient generator. I have to manually type the "source code" section to dynamically render with the state. Although, I would love if I could just grab the code from the dom itself after its rendered.
[image: Picture in question]

Comment: This is pretty much doable :) Can I have a look at your Code. You can share the codesandbox link :)

Comment: There :)
https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-leftpad-4xif5?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This shows none of your code My Friend :) Save it once :)

Answer (score 0):

Using `useRef Hook` and `useEffect` Hook it can be achieved.

Here are the steps:

1. Set a state for your gradient colors, so that `onChange` on the color element will store the color in the particular state for both the colors.
2. Make use of `useRef` Hook in your component.

   ```
   const myGradient = useRef(null);
   ```

   Use `ref={myGradient}` with your div element that shows current Gradient being selected.
3. In the `useEffect()` use second argument as state of your colors so that whenever you select a new color `useEffect()` gets invoked.
4. Then Inside you useEffect() you can make use of normal Javascript to first have access to the `myGradient` div with `myGradient.current`. Then write your logic to get the style from it and show it on the particular div.

   Something like
   `myGradient.current.textContent = linear-gradient(117deg,${color1},${color2})`; // I am using template literals here from start of `linear-gradient` to the end `)`